# Tornado for python 2.7 requires asyncio which is python 3+ only

Tags: python-2.7, tornado, gremlin, python-asyncio

I started using gremlinclient which needs to be Tornado for websockets. However Tornado uses asyncio module which requires Python 3+. Considering Tornado is Python 2.7 compatible I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get asyncio working with it.

What am I missing? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tornado can run on asyncio's IOLoop, but it is not required to. **It is not in requirements of Tornado** (even 4.3), you should install it with no problems. Even though asyncio has been ported to python 2.7 - [trollius](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius).

Btw I am using Tornado on 2.7 without asyncio/trollius.

Answer (score 0):

[Tornado is also compatible with Python 3](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Quoting from the documentation link above (emphasis mine):

> Prerequisites: Tornado 4.3 runs on Python 2.6, 2.7, **and 3.2+** (support for Python 2.6 and 3.2 is deprecated and will be removed in the next release). For Python 2, version 2.7.9 or newer is strongly recommended for the improved SSL support. In addition to the requirements which will be installed automatically by pip or setup.py install, the following optional packages may be useful:

Comment: Thanks but knowing this doesn't help me run tornado+asyncio in Python 2.7.  is there an alternative for Python 2.7?

Comment: @AtharvaI I fear not: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html aysncio is new in Python 3.4

Comment: yup, my question is is there an alternative to be used with Tornado, I couldn't find with Google.